# How to do the Global search on sharepoint using azure cognitive search

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Let's say I have multiple sites under the root sharepoint, https://.sharepoint.com/
Now instead of search through individual sites and indexing them, is there a way to create only one index which includes multiple sites and on querying, we will get the results from the respective site.

I have created the datasource with the root folder, or root site url

{
"name": "sharepoint-gloabalsearch-datasource1",
"type": "sharepoint",
"credentials": {
"connectionString": "SharePointOnlineEndpoint=https://.sharepoint.com/;ApplicationId="";ApplicationSecret="";TenantId="""
},
"container": {
"name": "allSiteLibraries",
"query": "includeLibrariesInSite=https://.sharepoint.com/"
}

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information, you can create an index that includes multiple SharePoint sites.

In your data source configuration, you can use the `includeLibrariesInSite` keyword to index content from all libraries under the specified site in the connection string, including any `subsites`

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/search-howto-index-sharepoint-online.md#controlling-which-documents-are-indexed), `If you need content from subsites, choose "useQuery" and specify "includeLibrariesInSite".`

Possible alternate solution can be with creating a search schema that includes all the fields that you want to index from the different sites.
You can then create a search index that uses this schema and configure it to crawl the different sites.